Shopware 6.6 Opensearch prefix filter looks for the first letter of every word of a field instead of first letter of that field
I need to search products of which name starts with a specific letter or number.
Thus, I added the prefix filter as a normal shopware filter and then gets passed into elasticsearch:
$criteria->addFilter(new PrefixFilter('name', $searchTerm));

The mapping on the name field of the product is this one (shopware default, not altered):

Down the line the prefix filter gets turned by shopware elasticsearch into:

The result is that shopware doesn't look for products of which name starts with a letter (in this case E) but products which have words starting with that letter in their name:

Can I change it so that the prefix search looks at the starting of the phrase only instead of each separated word in the name?
